# qHow to change image of div on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to change icon when it is clicked or focused, and back to normal when its not.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmy3d95g/)

In fiddle, when we click on icon the image changes but it doesn't change back to original one when the other icons were clicked.

Please help

My html code:

```
<div style="width:95%;background:#fff">
    <div style="width:32%;float:left;margin-right:1%;margin-left:2%;"><table style="border:0;width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">YEARS OF EXPERTISE & EXPERIENCE</p>
    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%"><img class="SerV-Image 1a" id="1" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/32.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">COMPREHENSIVE CONSULTANCY</p>
    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%"><img class="SerV-Image 2a" id="2" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/22.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">THE BEST QUALITY APPS</p>
    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%"><img class="SerV-Image 3a" id="3" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/32.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table></div><div style="width:27%;float:left;margin-right:3%;height:50px"></div><div style="width:35%;float:left">
    <table style="border:0;width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">YEARS OF EXPERTISE & EXPERIENCE</p>
    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%"><img class="SerV-Image 4a" id="4" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/42.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">COMPREHENSIVE CONSULTANCY</p>
    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%"><img class="SerV-Image 5a" id="5" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/52.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:70%"><p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">THE BEST QUALITY APPS</p>
    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%"><img class="SerV-Image 6a" id="6" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/42.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

My Jquery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".SerV-Image").on('click', function(){
    var id = this.id;


        if(id == 1){
    $("#"+id).attr('src','http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 2){
    $("#"+id).attr('src','http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 3){
    $("#"+id).attr('src','http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 4){
    $("#"+id).attr('src','http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover.png');
    }
    if(id == 5){
    $("#"+id).attr('src','http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/5hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 6){
    $("#"+id).attr('src','http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover.png');
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Please strip out the not needed parts for demonstration, so it will be more clearer code for the ones who are trying to help you.

Comment: Try looking into the `.toggle()` function and name your images exactly the same, but add something like "active" for the one that shows if an icon is active. Then on click, let jquery add or remove `active` to your img-url. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: hey @devqon thanks for your suggestion, i already did stripout the code.

Comment: @Rvervuurt i used the toggle function, but its not helping.

Comment: Why don't you use `:focus` pseudo-selector in your CSS instead of doing this with JS? Actually, why aren't you using CSS at all? Inline-style are a _bad_ idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since you wanted the click event then keep track of the previous ID it is really simple:

```
var previousId = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".SerV-Image").on('click', function(){
    var id = this.id;

    if(id == 1){
        $("#"+id).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 2){
        $("#"+id).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 3){
        $("#"+id).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 4){
        $("#"+id).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover.png');
    }
    if(id == 5){
        $("#"+id).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/5hover1.png');
    }
    if(id == 6){
        $("#"+id).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover.png');
    }

    if(previousId == 1)
    {
        $("#"+previousId).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/32.png');
        //set id=1 back to its original src if it was the previously selected item
    }
    if(previousId == 2)
    {
        $("#"+previousId).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/22.png');
    }
    if(previousId == 3)
    {
        $("#"+previousId).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/32.png');
    }
    if(previousId == 4)
    {
            $("#"+previousId).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/42.png')        
    }    
    if(previousId == 5)
    {
            $("#"+previousId).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/52.png')        
    }    
    if(previousId == 6)
    {
            $("#"+previousId).attr('src','http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/42.png')        
    }    

    previousId = id; // set previousId to the one you just changed
    });
});
```

Here you set when you click an object you set its src to the hover but then you find the previous id clicked and unselect it by setting its src back to its original.

Hope this helps

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmy3d95g/8/

*** UPDATED TO WORK FOR ALL ITEMS ***

PS you also didn't have a `.SerV-Image{` in your CSS so that wasn't working

Comment: What i want is, image of icon changed when it got clicked not on hover.

Comment: Added reset for all images, and working JSFiddle so you can see it working as you wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
/* Lets put your code in a separate function because we will use it for two events.*/
function hover(id, on){
    /* ON will tell us if the mouse entered or left (true of false)*/
    if(on){
        /* We will add a data-original to save the original image src the first time we run this function*/
        if(typeof $("#" + id).attr("data-original") === "undefined"){
            $("#" + id).attr("data-original", $(this).attr("src"));
        }
        var src = "";
        /* A switch statement is easier then your if/else since you're using numbered IDs*/
        switch(id){
            case 1: src = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png"; break;
            case 2: src = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2-hover1.png"; break;
            case 3: src = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/3-hover1.png"; break;
            case 4: src = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover1.png"; break;
            case 5: src = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/5-hover1.png"; break;
            case 6: src = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/6-hover1.png"; break;
        }
        /* Here we apply the src to the id. */
        $("#" + id).attr("src", src);
    } else {
        /* When the mouseleaves (ON is false), we put back the original image. */
        if(typeof $("#" + id).attr("data-original") != "undefined"){
            var src = $("#" + id).attr("data-original");
            $("#" + id).attr("src", src);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    /* on mouseover/mouseleave we will pass the id to the function */
    $(".SerV-Image").on('mouseover', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        hover(id, true);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        hover(id, false);
    });
});
```

Important to know: IDs can actually not start with numbers, you should make them start with a character. So name your divs div_[number] and filter out the div when passing it to the function (`this.id.replace("div_", "")`) and replace are reference of `$("#" + id)` with `$("#div_" + id)`.

Important to remember is that this is **inherently a bad way** to do hover styling. Users without javascript won't see it, and `hover` states are incredibly well supported in CSS. So please think of  putting your CSS in a separate CSS file and using the `:hover` state to allow the browser to do all this *for you* and *at native speeds*.

### Update

The above also works with other browser events, like `onclick` or `onfocus` and `onblur`. Just add the event to the jquery `.on()` and then pick the right `ON` value to pass (so if you want this on focus, like your title suggests, do: `$(".SerV-Image").on('focus', function(){var id = this.id; hover(id, true);}).`)

Comment: thanks for your help but What i want is, image of icon changed when it got clicked not on hover.

Comment: Check my change. You can replace the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` with any other events. Please look up some more about events, as they are very interchangeable and you should do some effort to understand them before using them. Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var idMap = ['',    // This will be idMap[0], which we wont use.
    'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png',
    'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2hover1.png',
    'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png',
    'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover.png',
    'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/5hover1.png',
    'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-hover.png'
];
var active = {
    state: false,
    element: undefined,
    src: undefined
};

$(".SerV-Image").on('click', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var originalSrc;
    var target;

    if (active.state && (active.element && (active.element.id !== id))) {
        active.element.attr('src', active.src);
    }

    target = $('#' + id);

    originalSrc = target.attr('src');
    target.attr('src', idMap[id]);

    active.state = true;
    active.element = target;
    active.src = originalSrc;
});
});
```

Added an 'idMap' to store your images. This wont work with non incremental id's, but in your case the id's starts on 1 and then up.

Added an 'active' object with properties to keep check on the currently clicked element and it's previous state.

When clicking on a bound item the code checks if there's already an active element and resets that. Then sets itself as the active element.

If you find anything unclear I'd be happy to explain it to my best extent.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example for your solution. [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmy3d95g/10/)

I stripped down your html and changed your javascript code as following

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function resetAllIcons() {
 $(".SerV-Image").each(function () {
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-original-src"))
 })
    }
    resetAllIcons()
    $(".SerV-Image").on("click", function () {
 resetAllIcons()
 $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-hover-src"))
    })
});
```

```css
.SerV-Image{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:95%;background:#fff">
  <div style="width:32%;float:left;margin-right:1%;margin-left:2%;">
    <table style="border:0;width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:70%">
          <p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">
            YEARS OF EXPERTISE & EXPERIENCE
          </p>
          <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">
            djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl
          </span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30%">
          <img class="SerV-Image 1a" id="1" data-original-src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/32.png" data-hover-src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1-hover1.png" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:70%">
          <p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 5px 0">
            COMPREHENSIVE CONSULTANCY
          </p>
          <span style="font-size:10px;margin:0 0 5px 0">
            djsadsadkldksaldk lkdlsakd ksldk lksldkl
          </span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30%">
          <img class="SerV-Image 2a" id="2" data-original-src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/22.png" data-hover-src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2hover1.png" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width:27%;float:left;margin-right:3%;height:50px">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this answer is better compared to the others. I think this should be marked as correct.